# How to Ensure All Language Files Are Updated with New Keys in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, translation

I am working on a Laravel project with multiple language support and I've recently added a new key-value pair to my `en/messages.php` file:

```php
'back' => 'Back'
```

I have multiple language files for different locales, such as vi, fr, id, etc., and I need to make sure that this new key is added to all of them with the appropriate translations.

Considering the large number of language files, it's quite challenging to manually check each file to confirm if the translation has been added. Is there an automated way or a tool within Laravel that can help me verify that all language files have been updated accordingly?

I'm looking for a solution that would either:

Alert me if a key is missing in any language file.
Provide a report of missing translations across all language files.
Any suggestions or best practices on how to manage this efficiently would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `php artisan translations:check` is not a default command in Laravel. To check translations, you might need to create a custom command or use a third-party package like Laravel Langman or Laravel Translation Manager. These packages provide functionality for managing and checking translations.

Comment: Thank you, I'm using this https://packagist.org/packages/barryvdh/laravel-translation-manager package because it has a user-friendly interface and it's easy to add languages.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [Laravel translations checker](https://github.com/LarsWiegers/laravel-translations-checker). Once the package is installed, you can run a check like this:

```
php artisan translations:check
```

Comment: I will consider it